# Using custom enums in a FlatBuffer

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

I'm using the [C++ API for FlatBuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_use_cpp.html) to store and retrieve preferences for a macOS application written in Objective-C.

Many of the preferences that I'm storing are typedef'd enums that I use throughout the application. Is there anyway to use those existing enums within a FlatBuffer schema such that I can use them as default values?

For example, I'd like to do the following:

```
  table Preferences {
    layout:int = FLLayoutModeList;
    sidebar:int = FLSidebarElementInspector;
  }
```

*Where `FLLayoutModeList` and `FLSidebarElementInspector` are defined as `FLLayoutMode` and `FLSidebarElement` enums respectively in my Objective-C.*

Can this be done using the C++ native types interface? Note that I'm only reading and writing this FlatBuffer from my own code. It is not being shared with other applications nor does it require any cross-language support, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for a schema to include definitions from something that is not a schema, i.e. C++ or Objective C code. The only way to not have to duplicate them is to define them in a FlatBuffers schema and use the generated code from there. It does not work the other way around.

Note that if you're using Objective C (as opposed to Objective C++) you could use the `flatcc` schema compiler to generate pure C, which may work better.

Comment: Thank you. I'll revisit flatcc but I'm also happy just using the C++ API as well. Thankfully, Objective-C++ works well enough for my basic needs.